# I want a live change event in input text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I want to handle change event in a text input field. but the event is triggered when the mouse loses focus on element.I want as-type-in change event triggered. what should i do for a live event in jQuery?

I've used :

```
jQuery('#element').on('change',function(){
//do the stuff
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event:

```
$('#someInput').keyup(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

there is also an input event:

```
$('#someInput').on('input', function() { 
    // Your code here
});
```

as [frnhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236195/frnhr) pointed out, it's better to use `input` event because: "input will handle any change - e.g. if you paste something in the field, input will trigger but keyup wont."

Comment: `input` will handle any change - e.g. if you paste something in the field, `input` will trigger but `keyup` wont.

Answer (score 4):

You've got three key-related events to choose from, `keyup`, `keydown` and `keypress`; assuming you type the string `abc`:

```
$('#demo').on('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(this.value);
});

// a
// ab
// abc
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBEd9/1/).

```
$('#demo').on('keydown', function(e){
    console.log(this.value);
});

// 
// a
// ab
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBEd9/3/).

```
$('#demo').on('keypress', function(e){
    console.log(this.value);
});

// 
// a
// ab
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBEd9/2/).

The difference is, as the output (roughly) shows, is that `keyup` and `keypress` respond *before* the value of the element is updated; so if you want to know the key that was pressed you have to use `e.which` (the jQuery normalized keypress event which returns the `keyCode` of the pressed-key) in both the `keypress` and `keyup` handlers and then add that to the `value` property. `e.which` will, under `keyup` *also* return the correct `keyCode`, but you *don't* have to manually add that key to get the updated `value`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `keyUp()`

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's 2021, this can be done with "input" as well.
But you might need to have a look at Vue.js were it's much easier to accomplish this.

```
jQuery(document).on('input', '#element', function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var target = $('.target');
    var fallbackName = target.attr('data-fallback-text'); // Can be handy

    liveInputChange(input, target, fallbackName);
});

function liveInputChange(input, target, fallbackName) {

    if (input === "" || input === null) {
        target.text(fallbackName);
    } else {
        target.text(input);
    }
}
```